# hashMap is filled with Objects that are casted beforehand. Is there Nullpointer potential if we use get() with another cast object?

Tags: java, casting, nullpointerexception, hashmap

The system I try to debug is relatively complex, so I'll limit it to the classes/methods that I assume to cause the Nullpointer.

I have a class `Cloudlet` which among other fields has a unique `int cloudletId` used to identify it. I have a class `Task extends Cloudlet`. I have a hashMap `HashMap<Task,Double> averageComputationTimes`. I have a `List<Cloudlet> cloudlets` that contains all the cloudlet objects of interest.

I populate `averageComputationCosts` like this:

```
for (Object cloudlet : getCloudletList()) {
    Task t = (Task) cloudlet;
    double sum = computationCosts.get(t).values().stream().reduce(0.0,Double::sum);
    averageComputationCosts.put(t, sum/computationCosts.get(t).size());
}
```

At another place in my code I get a Nullpointer:

```
double max = averageComputationCosts.get(task); // task is again cast and taken from getCloudletList()
```

Can this happen because the `Task` objects that are created are cast from `Cloudlet` and hence have a different `hashCode` value?

Comment: If both theses snippets cause an NPE, have you checked that `averageComputationCosts` or its entries are not `null`?

Comment: No, the cast doesn't change the reference/value of the object. If you get null pointer, is because the map averageComputationCosts doesn't contain the task you're searching.

Comment: @f1sh OP gets an NPE because of the unboxing of a null into a primitive, the null coming because the task looked for has no equivalent hash in the map. While the duplicate you reference is very often the answer, I don't think it is this time.

Comment: Have you defined the contract of Task objects? specifically equals() and hashCode() ?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ the cause is still the same. OP accesses hashmap entry with a `null` value. The reason i marked it as a duplicate is that the process of finding out what exactly is `null` is the same: looking at the stacktrace. The autounboxing is just one more circumstance.

Comment: @f1sh I disagree, the issue here is that the task used to get from the map is not found, maybe because it's really not there, maybe because the equals/hashCode are not correctly implemented for Task class. It happens to raise a NPE because of the unboxing but it's just a side effect in this case. Anyway, it seems you outnumber me on that :)